# How to remove android tab widget border lines?

Tags: android, tabs, android-tabhost, tabwidget, android-tabactivity

I have a android tab host activity and I want to remove the border lines between the tabs

a default tab widget looks like this:

Tab1|Tab2|Tab|

but I want it to appear like this:

Tab1 Tab2 Tab3

How can I obtain this kind of look on my android tab widget. I also tried to put `tabStripEnable = "false"` but nothing happened.

Comment: which  divice do u testing

Comment: im testing it on an emulator, a nexus 5 clone

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change tab background color and remove divider line between tabs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6197856/change-tab-background-color-and-remove-divider-line-between-tabs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
tabHost.getTabWidget().setDividerDrawable(null);
or 
tabHost.getTabWidget().setStripEnabled(true);    
tabHost.getTabWidget().setRightStripDrawable(android.R.color.transparent);
tabHost.getTabWidget().setLeftStripDrawable(android.R.color.transparent);
```

or

```
 tabHost.getTabWidget().setRightStripDrawable(pass blue colour);
 tabHost.getTabWidget().setLeftStripDrawable(pass blue colour);
```

Comment: I have a follow up questions sir, how can I also remove those color blue underline indicators on my tab widget?

Comment: pass any colour in place of android.R.color.transparent

Comment: what method should I use?